# *max_element for finding maximum value in a range

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there an alternative for *max_element for finding the value of the maximum element in an array for a given range. I want to avoid loop and STL both.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the tools provided? Whatever that reason is, if there is an alternative solution, there is a good chance it will also be unacceptable for the same reasons.

Comment: [`boost::range::max_element`](https://greek0.net/boost-range/boost-range-max_element.html)?

Comment: Whatever the reasons for this question, I don't think you can find the maximum of some elements without iterating all over them. You have to use one of the two things, I mean if you don't want to use loops, You can probably go for ```priority_queues```, but that is also an STL component, but, alternatively all these built-in algorithms and structures internally use ```loops``` and ```comparison model``` to find the max of all elements.

Comment: As others have suggested,  a requirement to avoid using available features of the language (loops) or standard library is rather a poor requirement.   You could write a recursive function - take care to specify the end condition properly.    Technically, however, the compiler may convert such a function into a loop   (e.g.   if it is tail recursive).    And it uses other capabilities of the language .....

Comment: Sort then take the last element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive approach if you want to avoid loop or any STL function.

A roughly drafted code would look like this

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;

int maxInt;
int maxRecur(int* arr, int length)
{
    if (length == 0)
        return maxInt;
    else
        if (maxInt < *arr)
            maxInt = *arr;
    maxRecur(arr+1, length-1);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = { 1,4,9,3,2 };
    cout << maxRecur(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
}
```